# Font Rendering Broken When It Comes To Small Slanted Fonts

Tags: fonts, instant-messaging

I was using Discord on my AOKP 7.1 GM7102 and there was a message that looked like this.

[image: Discord]

I copy-pasted one of the text in a text program -Xplore Text Editor- in the phone and the same boxes appear when I copy to the notes app. I sent the file to the PC and this is how it looks like.

[image: Windows]

When opening in Word. Out of major encodings, apparently only UTF-8 worked rest were messed up and weirdly when I selected the text it was half the length of the selection box.

So how do I fix that? I once changed Roboto-Regular with Lucida Console.ttf but I don't think it's related. Changing to the online Roboto-Regular download didn't help either.

This is probably an app-based problem but I want to know if it has something to do with Android in general.

Here is direct copy-paste from the Discord browser.

> If you are considering leaving the squadron please DM me and you will be dismissed accordingly also please provide a reason for  leaving and the name of the squadron you are transferring to (if that is applicable)
> REDACTED
> Please fill out the following in #apply-here if you are interested, or DM me if you have problems!
> 1)   - ?
> 2)   - ?
> 3)      ?
> 4)          ?
> 5)Are you able to participate in Squadron Realistic Battles?
> 6)        ?    ?
> 7)       =Redacted= - ?
> 8)What is your age?
> REDACTED27.07.2020
> Please respect the chain of command and understand what roles do what.
> Deputy/colonel has equal permissions as commander.
> Officers can accept your ingame application and is an admin on the discord.
> Sergeants are moderators on the discord and can only control WWM ingame.
> The purpose of this message is to prevent things like this happening again

Comment: Tbh I think this is more of an OS issue, fixable only by an upgrade or possibly by root. Is the text visible in any other app?

Comment: @SSS all apps show the same rectangles. AOKP is rooted